# How does the webserver know where the website is?

Tags: http, webserver

For example, when I type `stackoverflow.com`, I understand how the correct webserver is found. But how does the webserver know which folder to show?

I would guess that there is some kind of config for domain->folder? How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

by visiting `stackoverflow.com` you open the `/` route so it searches about this route in its routes and runs the function with this route

Comment: Where does it search for this route?

Comment: each server has its URLs file like Django .... in Flask and other frameworks it's added py decorator if it doesn't find it , it will return 404 Not Found